# while selecting ejs-grid row publish button getting enabled but unable to click selenium java angular

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ejs

I am selecting a row in angular ejs-grid using selenium test ng java.  Below statement hovers over the row
but  publish button just appears ENABLED in the below statement js .executeScript not getting clicked.

```
action.moveToElement(modalitiesSchedulesRowsListArray.get(2)).click(modalitiesSchedulesRowsListArray.get(2)).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('a')).click(e).perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-tabContent > ittf-schedule-list > div.tab-pane.fade.show.active > div:nth-child(1) > div.col-md-4.text-right > div > button")));
```

I want to select the row that the row appears selected and PUBLISH button gets ENABLED.
I want to select all rows in the table using `CTRL+a` OR ANY FEATURE.